# Running PowerShell with admin credentials for users

Tags: powershell, printing

I have a PowerShell script that restarts the Spooler service, then locates all printers with a specific name, removes those printers, then adds the printers back. I want to be able to go on a user's PC and run the script and input my admin credentials, but when I do, it doesn't find the printers because printers are per user not per PC. Is there a way to run the script as the user with elevated permissions in a single PS instance?

```
 # Check if ps is running as admin otherwise open this script as admin
if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) { Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`"" -Verb RunAs; exit }


 # Local printer name to search for
$FindName = "*DSM*"

# Store local printer object for later use
$Printers = Get-Printer -Name $FindName

if(!$Printers){
    $NotFound = "No printer with the name " 
    $NotFound2 = " was found."
    $NotFound + $FindName + $NotFound2
}else{
    Write-Output "Printer found"

    # Restart spooler service
    Write-Output "Restarting Spooler"
    Restart-Service -Name Spooler -Force

    # Wait for Spooler to come back online
    Start-Sleep -s 5

    # loop through all printers found and re-add each one
    foreach($Printer in $Printers){
        # Remove printer
        Write-Output "`nRemoving " $Printer.Name
        Remove-Printer -Name $Printer.Name
    
        # Add printer
        Write-Output "Re-adding " $Printer.Name
        Add-Printer -ConnectionName $Printer.Name
    }
    Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"
}
```

Comment: Can't you run Powershell as admin?

Comment: I can, but when running it as admin it does not find any printers since it is searching under the admin name for the printers.

Comment: Run the script as the user you want to remove the per-user printers from, not your admin user.

Comment: Restart-Service requires admin permissions to work.

Comment: Then you will need to launch a second powershell process under your user to perform the service restart. I've written a few answers on how to do run commands as another user, let me find one and link you to it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to run the service management pieces as an admin user (presumably, end users don't have admin on their workstations) but the printer management must happen from the end user's account. You'll essentially use `Start-Process` to run the service management piece as your admin account, but let the rest of the script run in the end user's context:

```
# Restart spooler Service
# Splatting used here for readability

$psPath = "$env:SystemRoot/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe"

$spArgs = @{
  Wait = $True
  Credential = Get-Credential DOMAIN.tld\adminuser
  FilePath = $psPath
  ArgumentList = '-Command "$p = Start-Process -PassThru -Wait -FilePath \"{0}\" -Verb RunAs -ArgumentList \"Restart-Service -Force -EA Stop spooler\"; exit $p.ExitCode"' -f $psPath
  PassThru = $True
  ErrorAction = 'Stop'
}

$p = Start-Process @spArgs

if( $p.ExitCode -ne 0 ) {
  # The service failed to restart. Handle the failure case.
}
```

The way this works:

- Run a new `powershell.exe` process as your admin user, then making sure to elevate permissions by ***running `powershell.exe` a second time*** with the `RunAs` Verb. You will need to input the credential each time the script is run.

  - As indicated in the comments, `-Credential` and `-Verb` are mutually exclusive.
  - There is not really a graceful way to do this, to make this most readable I have use a literal string with the format operator `-f` to avoid an even worse escape-hell.
  - The `-Command` parameter needs to be provided within double-quotes when executed via `Start-Process`, or else it will only render the literal string and not actually execute the nested command.
- The youngest PowerShell process will perform the service restart.
- Use the `-Wait` flag to wait until the process exits for both invocations of `Start-Process`. `Start-Process` does not block execution by default regardless of application type.
- Make `Restart-Service` throw a terminating error with `-EA Stop` if it encounters a problem. This will guarantee a non-zero exit code is returned on failure without requiring additional boilerplate code.
- Specifying the full path to `powershell.exe` is optional but a general good practice. You could also simply use `powershell.exe` in place of the full path to the binary.
- Programs run with `Start-Process` do not set `$LASTEXITCODE`. Therefore, we return the `Process` object with `-Passthru`, then check that its exit code is `0`. Any other exit code indicates failure for this operation.
- You can remove your admin check from the script since this no longer needs administrative permissions, and `Get-Credential` will essentially elevate for the service restart.

---

Note that if you want to perform this from a user who *can* elevate but you don't want the PowerShell script itself to run elevated, you can run the script without elevation and use the technique above but omit the `-Credential` parameter which becomes redundant. It would still work but no reason to authenticate when you don't have to.

Comment: Appreciate your help although I am running into an error.  
  


`Line |
  32 |      $p = Start-Process @spArgs
     |           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     | Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters. One or more parameters issued cannot be used together or an insufficient number of parameters were provided.`

Comment: I forgot, you can't call Verb and Credential at the same time. You'll have to nest one more process call. I'll update the sample above shortly.

Comment: Thank you. I'm very new to PowerShell otherwise I would have tried to work it out myself.

Comment: I've updated the code sample, nesting a second invocation of PowerShell can suck when you have to escape things perfectly, and the `ArgumentList` parameter doesn't follow the same escaping rules as PowerShell string during invocation.

Comment: I think the $psPath was incorrect so I changed it to `$psPath = "$env:SystemRoot\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe"` I am getting error: "This command cannot be run due to the error: The directory name is invalid." though. Not sure if that is referring to the ps path but that is the correct path.

Comment: I just pasted the code in my answer verbatim (you can *generally* use both forward and backward slashes for the directory separator in PowerShell) and it works as written (with my own user specified). I don't see how the directory separator would matter here but try it as I wrote it first.